# POSTGRES Update with left outer join is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, left-join

Please suggest, what am I doing wrong.

```
UPDATE uc 
SET uc.selected_value_id = cv.id, uc.fixed_value = NULL
FROM unit_characteristic uc
left JOIN characteristic_value cv ON uc.fixed_value like CONCAT(cv.value,'%')  
WHERE cv.characteristic_id = 6 
and uc.characteristic_id = 6
and uc.unit_id in (6313,6314)
```

Getting error

SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "uc" does not exist
Position: 8
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "uc" does not exist
Position: 8

While this select is working fine

```
select count(uc.*)   
FROM unit_characteristic uc
left JOIN characteristic_value cv ON uc.fixed_value like CONCAT(cv.value,'%')  
WHERE cv.characteristic_id = 6 
and uc.characteristic_id = 6
and uc.unit_id in (6313,6314)
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... FROM LEFT JOIN` make no sense anyway. Fortunately, the `WHERE cv.characteristic_id = 6` turns the LEFT join into a normal inner join.

Comment: There is no difference if i use left join or where, both the time getting the same error.

Comment: The comment whas about semantics, not about the syntax.

Comment: (Re wildplasser's comments, which are about your code but not your error message:) LEFT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT JOIN ON, a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, the reference in the `update` cannot refer to a table in the `from`.  I suspect you want:

```
update unit_characteristic uc 
    set selected_value_id = cv.id,
        fixed_value = NULL
from characteristic_value cv 
where uc.fixed_value like cv.value || '%' and
      cv.characteristic_id = 6 and
      uc.characteristic_id = 6 and
      uc.unit_id in (6313, 6314);
```

Note that your version of the query uses `left join`.  But the `where` clause turns that into an inner join anway.

Comment: Still getting the error SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "uc" of relation "unit_characteristic" does not exist
  Position: 40
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "uc" of relation "unit_characteristic" does not exist
  Position: 40

Comment: @TanuGarg . . . All the comparisons and column references come from your query.  You have not specified the tables or provides sample data.  So fix the conditions so they match your data.

Comment: got the solution. it was the alias with column names which was causing the issue.
update public.unit_characteristic uc set selected_value_id = cv.id, fixed_value = NULL from public.characteristic_value cv where uc.fixed_value like cv.value || '%' and cv.characteristic_id = 6 and uc.characteristic_id = 6

Comment: @TanuGarg . . . They are not needed for the left side of the `set`.

Answer (score 0):

- you don't have to repeat the *target* table in the `FROM` clause; it is already in the range table
- the target table *can* have an alias
- but, the `SET columnname = new_value` line **must not** use this alias. It is implicit (since there is only one table reference to be updated)

---

```
UPDATE unit_characteristic uc 
   SET selected_value_id = cv.id
     , fixed_value = NULL
FROM characteristic_value cv 
WHERE uc.fixed_value like cv.value || '%'
 AND cv.characteristic_id = 6
 AND uc.characteristic_id = 6
 AND uc.unit_id in (6313, 6314)
   ;
```

Comment: got the solution. it was the alias with column names which was causing the issue.

Comment: update public.unit_characteristic uc 
    set selected_value_id = cv.id,
        fixed_value = NULL
from public.characteristic_value cv 
where uc.fixed_value like cv.value || '%' and
      cv.characteristic_id = 6 and
      uc.characteristic_id = 6

Comment: That's what I wrote.